# Accessing Another Submodule From a Submodule

Tags: python, module, git-submodules, python-module

I'm trying to develop a program but I had issues in packaging and getting access in modules or submodules. Here is my file scheme for example:

```
src \
|__ module \
|  |__ sub \
|  |  |__ __init__.py
|  |  |__ example.py
|  |__ __init__.py
|__ submodule \
|  |__ __init__.py
|  |__ example_sub.py
|__ __init__.py
```

```py
# in src/submodule/example_sub.py

def print_example():
    print("I'm src/submodule")
```

```py
# in src/module/sub/example.py

from src.submodule.example_sub import print_exanple

print_example()
```

when I type

```bash
py .\module\sub\example.py
```

I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\example\src\module\sub\example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.submodule.example_sub import print_example
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I say okay. Lets try another thing. I'm trying to change the importing like

```py
from ..module import * # etc
```

but I can't get the submodule folder because its up 2 folders.

What should I do?

I tried to change directories. Tried to create package(but i think it didn't worked). Created and modified **init**.py file. But get no result, still same error.

Comment: If you use absolute imports (`from src.submodule.example_sub import print_exanple`), then can run it with `py -m src.module.sub.example` if you are in the `C:...\Desktop\example` directory.

Comment: @jfschaefer but what if i have more then 3 modules?

Comment: I don't think anything would change with more than 3 modules. You can use absolute imports and then run in the same way.